# Programmatically change "Scope Display Group" order

Tags: search-scope

I'm working with some custom search scopes, and adding them to a Scope Display Group. I'm wondering if it's possible to programmatically change the order within a display group, depending which site is being viewed.

For example: Let's say my site has 4 areas

```
Marketing: US
Marketing: French
Support: Version 1
Support: Version 2
```

I've created custom scopes for each, using the names above. I also added them to a Scope Display Group in the order above.

Now let's say I'm viewing the Support: Version 1 site of my site collection. What I'd like to see is:

```
Support: Version 1
Support: Version 2
Marketing: US
Marketing: French
```

Or, say, I'm in the French site of the site collection. I'd like to see this:

```
Marketing: French
Marketing: US
Support: Version 1
Support: Version 2
```

Anyone know if this is possible?

I'm expecting that a Visual Studio based solution may be the only way, which is fine. I think I'd just need a nudge in the right direction to be able to locate the display group and change the order in a User Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your problem in various ways:

1. Change per sitecollection the order of the scopes in the displaygroup that you are using
2. Add 2 site collection type displaygroups, either one with the correct order. Create the displaygroups in a feature, with the correct order of scopes in that group, and use the correct displaygroup for your searchbox.

the code you could use as example is:

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
RemoteScopes remoteScopes = new RemoteScopes(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
var displayGroups = remoteScopes.GetDisplayGroupsForSite(new Uri(site.Url));
var displayGroup = SelectDisplayGroup(displayGroups);  // select correct displaygroup

// insert logic to add/remove scopes, to put the scopes in the correct order
displayGroup.RemoveAt(i) // displayGroup.Remove(scope)
displayGroup.Insert(i, scope)
```

the object model doesn't support moving scopes around besides the explicit removal and addition of scopes. (as far as i know ;))

Comment: Thanks, @Bas-Lijten - I think that's just the information I needed. I've done some work with `RemoteScopes` before but not spotted the `GetDisplayGroupsForSite` method. I should be able to take this info and produce just what I need :)

Comment: make sure to cast the objects within the IEnumerable that is returned to the ScopeDisplayGroup, otherwise, you won't be able to remove or insert the items